# simulink block to convert a matrix

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a 1x512 matrix "u" that I need to convert to 1x128 using the following formula:

ua = u(1:128)+u(129:256)+u(257:384)+u(385:512)

This works in the workspace, but not in simulink.  I've tried adding an Fcn function block and get an this error:

```
Error while parsing expression: u(1:128)+u(129:256)+u(257:384)+u(385:512)
in 'osverlapsave/Fcn' token ":" was found, where as ")" was expected
```

I found this in the Fcn block help file "this block does not support the colon operator (:)."

Do I need to use a different block type?

Comment: 2 questions: why do you need to do this in Simulink? and can you tell us which block exactly you used (it's not clear from your question), and what the actual code is, and also what is the input to the block?

Comment: the block is called Fcn "Apply specified expression to input". The input to block is the output of an FFT block, wich contains 512 bins complex double values.

from the help file "u — The input to the block. If u is a vector, u(i) represents the ith element of the vector; u(1) or u alone represents the first element."  For some reason the block does not recognize the range operator ':'

Comment: Can you check the signal is actually of dimension 512? I suspect it isn't... http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/displaying-signal-properties.html#f15-90115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Fcn doesn't accept `:` when indexing, plus it doesn't accept complex inputs, only real inputs, so I wouldn't use it.

Instead, I would suggest using 4 [selector](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/selector.html) blocks and summing their outputs with a sum block, much easier.